# 6 Circle in Equilateral Triangle

Tags: geometry

i have one doubt in this when there are 6 circles in equilateral triangle then how the angle is 30 degree[image]

Comment: I'm afraid there are a bit more than $5$ circles in this triangle...

Comment: Notice the tangent to circle are triangle vertices

Comment: The center of the lower leftmost circle is equidistant to the sides of the $60^\circ$ angle, and thus the center lies on the angle bisector.

Comment: thnx david i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the diagram, both the triangles have one angle as 90 degree and two sides as same [1. radius of the triangle 2. common side]. So , both the triangles are congruent. [(The RHS rule: Right-angled, Hypotenuse, Side)]

  - Hence the angle of triangle will be divided as 60/2 = 30 degree.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFr3t.jpg)

Comment: Your diagram clearly shows how "properties of tangent pair" can be used to explain the doubt. It is dwonvoted probably because of not accompanied by any explanation.

Comment: ok @Mick , I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is $30^\circ$.  The line through the bottom left corner and the center of the bottom left circle is an angle bisector of the triangle's $60^\circ$ corner.  It must be an angle bisector since we know that at the point in the circle, the line is equidistant from both sides of the angle with distance $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more Geometric approach:

$OY$ is the radius of circle $O$ and is tangent to $\triangle ABC$.

From that, we have $\triangle YOC \cong\triangle XOC$ because $OY\cong XO$ and $CO\cong CO$. (HL congruency for right triangles)

Therefore, $\angle OCY\cong\angle OCX$. And since they add up to $60^{\circ}$, we have $$\angle OCY+\angle OCX=60\\2\angle OCY=60\\\angle OCY=\angle OCX=30^{\circ}$$

[image: Diagram]